# Confused about MIME types, Browser transformations and Transformations3-What are they?

Tags: apache-2.2, mysql

everyone. I'm new to Apache, and I'm trying to build a database in phpMyAdmin. When choosing the properties on the type of fields for a particular table design, there are three properties that I don't quite understand- MIME types, Browser transformations and Transformations3. Could somebody please explain these things to me? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TLDR Version**: 99.999% of the time you will ignore them and just leave them empty.

They are used as part of the advanced features of phpMyAdmin. The MIME Type is the file type for the contents of the file and the transformation is how it is 'altered' for presentation.

e.g. If you have an image stored in a table and you tried to view it in phpmyadmin it would just show a bunch of garbage text but if you set the correct MIME type for the image and the correct transformation it could instead show the picture.

For more information see [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME) for information on MIME Types and the [phpMyAdmin](http://www.mbar.org/webserv/phpmyadmin/Documentation.html#transformations) documentation for information on transformations

Comment: Thanks for the answer syserr0r, this was a good explanation

Comment: tl;dr it's a phpMyAdmin thing